# a function that is in $L^2$ but not in $L^p$ for $p < 2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I'm taking the space to be $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard (Lebesgue) measure on it. I need a function which, when squared, yields a convergent integral but when raised to any power between 1 and 2 (2 not inclusive), doesn't. Clearly this function can't have compact support...I can see that much. But I cannot think of an example of such a function.

Comment: $(1+|x| \log^2 |x|)^{-1/2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\int_2^{\infty}x^{-1}(\log x)^{-2}\,dx$ converges, so $f(x)=x^{-1/2}\log x$ should do (just define it to be zero for $x<2$).

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. My goal is to learn, so may I ask how you came up with this function, so that I might be able to follow your reasoning processes when I attempt to construct other examples of this sort?

Comment: I knew that $\int^{\infty}x^{-1}$ diverges, but just barely, in the sense that if you make the denominator grow a little faster, you get convergence. I had to do a little thinking and experimenting to remind myself that a factor of $(\log x)^2$ in the denominator would do the trick.